# How to change default search engine with JS api on android platform?

Tags: javascript, android, search-engine, mobile-browser

How to change default search engine with JS api on android platform?
we could set default search engine on iphone, not manually. But wonder how to do this on android.

Comment: Good question, but unfortunately in most cases the user does not want that the search engine is changed. Like the hole stupid spy tool bars that changes the search engine.

Comment: I know there may be no such JS api call in android but I still wonder.

`window.canSetSearchEngine()
window.getSearchEngine()
window.setSearchEngine(string)`

these are accessible on iPhone.

Comment: **balduran**, it is a closed API. It's working only a couple of sites.

Answer (score 0):

window.external.AddSearchProvider may be the closest one. But I never tested on Android before.

Firefox in PC pops a confirm box, with a checkbox to set it as default search engine.
Chrome in PC pops a confirm without checkbox, and cannot set it as default.
For IE, MSDN says they will give a confirm box with a checkbox to set as default.

reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_search_engines_from_web_pages
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa744112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx